# Unable to to show value in Entry widget in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

In this GUI application, simpleapp is the main window. As part of initializing simpleapp, I am trying to set the home directory for the application, using class setHomeDir to open a window so that I can confirm / set the current working directory. To begin with, I am unable to get the current working directory to display in the setHomeDir window i.e. I am not able to get `self.entryVariable.set(home)`   to work.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
import Tkinter, os


class simpleapp(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.geometry('500x300+200+50')
        self.home_dir=os.getcwd()
        self.t=setHomeDir(parent=self, home=self.home_dir)



class setHomeDir(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent, home):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.geometry('500x100+200+50')
        self.title('Set Home Directory')

        self.grid()

        #Input Box
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entryVariable.set(home) 
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')


        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp(None)
    app.title('Main Window')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why are you not able to get it to work? Is it throwing an error? What error? Are you certain the problem is when you're calling `self.entryVariable.set(home)`? It looks like you can't ever reach that line of code because you're calling `setHomeDir` with a variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no error, just a blank text box where a value is expected.  I do believe that line of code is being reached. E.g., if I look into app.t, then the value is present. i.e. app.t.entryVariable.get() does show the current directory stored as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you do not want multiple instances of Tk().  It gets confused when there is more than one instance, so use a Toplevel instead.

```
import Tkinter, os

class SimpleApp():
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry('500x300+200+50')
        self.parent.title('Main Window')
        self.home_dir=os.getcwd()

        ## pass same Tkinter instance to the class
        SetHomeDir(parent=self.parent, home=self.home_dir)

class SetHomeDir():
    def __init__(self,parent, home):
        self.parent = parent
        self.top=Tkinter.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.top.geometry('500x100+200+500')
        self.top.title('Set Home Directory')

        #Input Box
        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.top, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entryVariable.set(home) 
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.focus_set()

        self.top.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.top.resizable(True,False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tkinter.Tk()
    app = SimpleApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer stars with "Also...". What are you referring to? "Also" in relation to what?